# How to annotate a dataclass to have a return value based on the initialized value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

I have the following (stripped down) dataclass:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Union, Type

class BaseType: ...
class PathType(BaseType): ...
class DataType(BaseType): ...

_FinalTypes = Union[PathType, DataType]

@dataclass
class InterfaceInfo:
    what: Type[_FinalTypes]
    name: str

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> _FinalTypes:
        return self.what(*args, **kwargs)

print(InterfaceInfo(PathType, "path"))
print(InterfaceInfo(DataType, "path"))
```

But I'm uncertain on how to properly annotate it.
My purpose is actually that whatever type you pass in into the `__init__`-method, should come out of the `__call__` as a materialized object.

Because what I've written now, the type-checker will think it's possible to have an `InterfaceInfo` constructed with a PathType, and have a DataType-object come out of it.

If this would be a method, I could use `@overload` to type hint it, but this is a class, so I'm at a loss...
I've looked into TypeVar bound to the BaseType. But isn't the same possible then? Or will the type checker be smart enough to know a Type[PathType] comes in, and a PathType needs to come out?

How would one go to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To a certain extent, this is solved by defining your `InterfaceInfo` as [**generic**](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#user-defined-generic-types) in terms of the `what` type. So I would say you had the right idea about using a type variable.

Assume the following concrete `BaseType` subtypes:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class BaseType:
    pass


@dataclass
class PathType(BaseType):
    path: str


@dataclass
class DataType(BaseType):
    data: bytes
```

We define our type variable with an upper bound of `BaseType` and then annotate `what` as well as the `__call__` return with that type variable like so:

```py
# ... import BaseType, PathType, DataType

from typing import Any, Generic, TypeVar


_T = TypeVar("_T", bound=BaseType)


@dataclass
class InterfaceInfo(Generic[_T]):
    what: type[_T]
    name: str

    def __call__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> _T:
        return self.what(*args, **kwargs)
```

Usage:

```py
path_interface = InterfaceInfo(PathType, "foo")
data_interface = InterfaceInfo(DataType, "bar")

p = path_interface(path="spam/eggs")
d = data_interface(data=b"ff00")

print(p)
print(d)

# for mypy:
reveal_type(p)
reveal_type(d)
```

The `print` calls output:

```
PathType(path='spam/eggs')
DataType(data=b'ff00')
```

The `mypy` output:

```
note: Revealed type is "PathType"
note: Revealed type is "DataType"
```

What we wanted and expected.

The reason I started by saying *"to a certain extent"* is that the signature of the `__call__` method is obviously just a cheap workaround. A static type checker has no way to verify that the arguments we pass, when calling `path_interface` or `data_interface`, are compatible with the type of `what`.

I thought about this for a bit and could not come up with a type-safe solution that would allow annotating `__call__` as generic to *that* extent. Meaning the return type may be safe, but there is no safety in the constructor arguments. Maybe someone else knows a way or maybe the Python type system is just not suited for this.

Comment: You can, I think, trade the specificity of `type[_T]` for `Callable[P, _T]` (where `P` is an appropriately defined `ParamSpec`), then use `P.args` and `P.kwargs` to hint the arguments to `__call__`.

Comment: It's not clear that `InterfaceInfo` is needed at all, though. Why wrap a type in another type?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input @Daniil! I learned the `reveal_type` today :)

Comment: @chepner Good point. I thought so too, but I assume that the actual purpose of this construct was just lost during simplification. Maybe there is a use case and we just don't see it.